# Why does the sign of the second items is negative

Tags: calculus, integration

Consider
$$\int_0^{2\pi}dx\int_0^{\sin(x)} f(x,y)dy= \int_0^1dy\int_{\arcsin(y)}^{\pi-\arcsin(y)}f(x,y)dx-\int_{-1}^0dy\int_{\pi-\arcsin(y)}^{2\pi+\arcsin(y)}f(x,y)dx$$
My question is why the sign of the second item is negative?

Answer (score 0):

In the integral on the $LHS$, in the region $\pi\le x\le2\pi,-1\le y\le0,y$ ranges from $0\to\sin(x)$ for any value of $x$. In the corresponding term on the $RHS$, that is $\displaystyle\int_{-1}^0dy\int_{\pi-\arcsin(y)}^{2\pi+\arcsin(y)}f(x,y)dx,y$ ranges from $-1\to0$, which is the opposite direction. So we add a negative sign:$$-\int_{-1}^0dy\int_{\pi-\arcsin(y)}^{2\pi+\arcsin(y)}f(x,y)dx=\int^{-1}_0dy\int_{\pi-\arcsin(y)}^{2\pi+\arcsin(y)}f(x,y)dx$$

Answer (score 0):

Here is the step-by-step solution:
$$\begin{align}\int_0^{2\pi}dx\int_0^{\sin(x)} f(x,y)dy&=\int_0^{\pi}dx\int_0^{\color{green}{\sin(x)}} f(x,y)dy+\int_{\pi}^{2\pi}dx\int_0^{\color{green}{\sin(x)}} f(x,y)dy=\\
&=\int_0^{\pi}dx\int_0^{\color{green}{\sin(x)}} f(x,y)dy-\int_{\pi}^{2\pi}dx\int_{\color{blue}{\sin(x)}}^0 f(x,y)dy=\\
&=\int_0^1dy\int_{\arcsin(y)}^{\pi-\arcsin(y)}f(x,y)dx-\int_{-1}^0dy\int_{\pi-\arcsin(y)}^{2\pi+\arcsin(y)}f(x,y)dx.\end{align}$$
Refer to the graph:

[image]